# Is the extension normal and a little work check.

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, field-theory, extension-field, irreducible-polynomials

Let us consider the polynomial $f(x)=x^3+x^2-4x+1$. I was asked the following things:

(1) Prove that $f(x)$ has one and only one negative root.

For this I just used Bolzano's theorem and noticed it has one negative and two positive real roots.

(2) Is $f(x)$ irreducible over $\mathbb Q$?

I just checked it has no roots mod $2$.

(3) Prove that $\tau(\alpha)=1/(1-\alpha)$ is automorphism of $\mathbb Q(\alpha)$. (Here $\alpha$ is the negative root which exsistence we proved in (1)).

Here I did a pretty long calculations to check that $\tau$ really is automorphism.
Clearly $\mathbb Q(\alpha)=\{c_0+c_1 \alpha+c_2 \alpha^2 |c_i \in \mathbb Q\}$. So I took $a,b \in \mathbb Q(\alpha)$ and calculated

$$
\tau(a+b)=\tau(a_0+a_1\alpha+a_2\alpha^2+b_0+b_1\alpha+b_2\alpha^2)=a_0+a_1\tau(\alpha)+a_2\tau(\alpha)^2+b_0+b_1\tau(\alpha)+b_2\tau(\alpha)^2= \cdots = \tau(a)+\tau(b).
$$
And also that 
$$
\tau(ab)=\tau(a)\tau(b)
$$

(4) Is $\mathbb Q(\alpha)/\mathbb Q$ a normal extension?

I know that it is normal if it contains the remaining two positive real roots of the $f(x)$. However I have no idea how to prove/disaprove that since I dont know the roots explicitely.

So is my work correct so far and how to deal with the last question?

Comment: I don't get (3), you didn't define the map, you just said what it maps $\alpha$ to. Regarding $4$, check that $\dfrac 1{1-\alpha}$ is a root of $f(x)$. Can you conclude?

Comment: @GitGud Well I didn't get it either but that is all what was given. So I thought I have to do what I did above. And given your hint I can indeed conclude, thanks.